# Drawing Asteroids DVG vector objects

Tags: programming, arcade

I'm trying to draw the vector objects from the original coordinates of the Asteroids arcade game, starting with the ship [from here](https://www.computerarcheology.com/Arcade/Asteroids/VectorROM.html#player-ships), but I'm having trouble figuring it out and getting weird results. E.g. this code

```
ShipDir0:
0A90: 0F F6           SVEC    scale=02(/128) bri=0     x=-3      y=-2      (-6.0000, -4.0000)
0A92: C8 FA           SVEC    scale=03(/64)  bri=12    x=0       y=2       (0.0000, 8.0000)
0A94: BD F9           SVEC    scale=03(/64)  bri=11    x=-1      y=1       (-4.0000, 4.0000)
0A96: 00 65 00 C3     VEC     scale=06(/8)   bri=12    x=768     y=-256    (96.0000, -32.0000)
0A9A: 00 65 00 C7     VEC     scale=06(/8)   bri=12    x=-768    y=-256    (-96.0000, -32.0000)
0A9E: B9 F9           SVEC    scale=03(/64)  bri=11    x=1       y=1       (4.0000, 4.0000)
0AA0: 00 D0           RTS
```

is supposed to draw the first ship with no rotation, but of course the VEC commands coordinates are far too large.
[image: the ship at various rotations]
I'm assuming some kind of global scale factor but tried several powers of 2, but nothing lets my ship polyline look like the first frame of the Asteroids ship. Any ideas on how to translate to usable coordinates for lines?

Edit: I tried playing around with the disassembled coordinates and looked at the code. This is what happens when using the following input:
[image: screenshot of source code]

And here's the output of drawing the lines:

[image: Drawn scaled up by factor 4 to actually see enough details]

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/fadden/6502bench/blob/master/SourceGen/RuntimeData/Atari/VisDVG.cs) converts the DVG instructions to points and lines. It was used to generate the shapes in [this disassembly](https://6502disassembly.com/va-asteroids/Asteroids.html#SymShipDirPtrTbl). Comparing your approach to the code there may be revealing, e.g. the comment "This is not mentioned in any document I've found".

Comment: When trying to render the coordinates from that disassembly as line segments, I get a really weird shape (edited/appended the question).

Comment: The results are rendered with a scale factor of 4, just so the details can be seen to debug. Also the division by 16 in the case of the VCTR commands is just me randomly trying to draw something that makes sense. Without the /16 it looks even weirder.

Comment: Thanks for updating, as the addition finally shows what the problem was you were seeing. Which I guess helped a lot to generate a well fitting answer :)

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The weird results come from interpreting the vectors as absolute coordinates instead of relative coordinates. Let me demonstrate.

Here are the coordinates that you show in your example code. Plotting these as a regular list of X-Y coordinates in Mathematica gives me the same result as what you show:

[image: Graphics[Line[{ {-3,-2}/128256, {0,2}/64256, {-1,1}/64256, {786,-256}/8/16, {-786,-256}/8/16, {1,1}/64256 }]]]

(The result is flipped vertically because +Y is up in Mathematica graphics, the opposite of most graphics libraries.)

However, the list of coordinates are supposed to be interpreted as incremental instead of absolute (so each point's coordinate is relative to the previous point).  To get the absolute coordinates of each point, we need to sum all of the previous relative coordinates (this is `Accumulate` in Mathematica, `cumsum` in MATLAB, and `std::partial_sum` in C++):

[image: Graphics[Line[Accumulate@{ {-3,-2}/128256, {0,2}/64256, {-1,1}/64256, {786,-256}/8/16, {-786,-256}/8/16, {1,1}/64256 }]]]

This is looking better, but still not quite right. The final issue is with the scale factor of 256 for the `SVEC` instructions, it should be 1024 instead:

[image: Graphics[Line[Accumulate@{ {-3,-2}/1281024, {0,2}/641024, {-1,1}/641024, {786,-256}/8, {-786,-256}/8, {1,1}/641024 }]]]

By the way, I recommend the video [*Atari's Quadrascan Explained*](https://youtu.be/smStEPSRKBs) by Retro Game Mechanics Explained on YouTube, they do an excellent job covering all the details of the vector generator instruction format.

Comment: This certainly looks like a great answer, much better than my work-around.

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid :D I saw the dx, dy in front of me all the time but somehow treated them as absolutes instead of relative coords. Thanks a lot for the awesome enlightenment and bringing me out of the darkness ;) It works flawlessly now. If you multiply with 1024, the ship will be too large, though, so I kept the factor 256 for all SVEC commands (like the original disassembly comments suggested) but just divided the VEC commands coordinates by an additional factor of 4. Awesome and thanks again! The weird asteroid shapes are next on the menu.

Comment: I just can't believe how cool that Quadascan video is produced. My jaw literally dropped with all the cool vector animations in that video. One of the best YT videos I've ever watched!

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a specific program referenced, which means I'll toss in an Inkscape related option. I'm using v0.92, newer versions may have slight changes in menu or palette options. My approach would be to import the image, perform a Path, Trace Bitmap. I used these settings to get a "clean" trace:

[image: inkscape settings]

Even though the preview appears choppy, the result is clean:

[image: inkscape trace result]

The bitmap is on top, trace is below.

Next step is to use Path, Break Apart to split off the individual ships:

[image: split ships]

In order to see the individual vectors, change the fill to none (click on X in lower left corner of screen, note legend for fill/stroke settings), shift click on black square immediately adjacent to make stroke visible.

Use the Fill and Stroke palette (Control-Shift-F) to change the stroke thickness (stroke style) to a less "bulky" value. I used 0.05 which is rather thin but visible on my screen.

[image: thinner stroke]

Note that the results of the trace creates two (or more) lines for each object. Newer versions of Inkscape may have what is known as centerline trace, but I've not tinkered with that feature. Y- or X- shaped intersections create anomalies that may complicate matters.

Inkscape stores the objects in XML form and the editor can be presented with Control-Shift-X:

[image: xml editor with one path selected]

The text in the editor box will change with the object selected. If you need absolute coordinates, you can drag the desired item to place a vertex on the origin.

Once the process is completed to your satisfaction (delete the original bitmap), saving the file will create an SVG format document which can be opened in any text editor. Identifying the desired path numbers in advance would be advisable if this route is taken.

I would not suggest that this is the single best solution, but it's a possible one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the approach. If everything else fails, I'll try to extract the coordinates with such a workflow. But I very much prefer somehow directly extracting the object's coordinates from the code.